# unable to execute 'delete' query in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hbase

I am unable to execute 'delete' query in java. The query executes fine in command prompt. Following is the code.

```
   String deleteQuery = "delete from id_table where id ='1666';
   int result = Connection.createStatement().executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
```

I do not get any exceptions or error messages and the response of above code is '1', but the id's are not deleted from the DB. I have also tried following approach and here i get the response as 'false'.

```
   Statement stmt = null;
   stmt = hbaseConnection.createStatement();
   boolean result = stmt.execute("delete from id_table where id ='1666';");
   stmt.close();
```

Comment: have you set autocommit to true or did you commit the changes?

Comment: you may forget the 'executeUpdate()'

Comment: what does this have to do with hbase?  it does not support jdbc.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use stmt.executeUpdate(query) for any DELETE, UPDATE and INSERT queries, and use stmt.getUpdateCount() to check the deletion.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)

The result you are getting in your second code is simply that this SQL is not a SELECT
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)

Also, check the Connection commit parameter or use yourConnection.commit

Answer (score 0):

```
  con = new BddConection().getinstance();       
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    try {
        pst=con.prepareStatement("delete from table where id ='1666'");
        pst.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(projet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    }
```